# Js works in IE, Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Remote Control</title>
  </head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/../.." type="text/css" />
<title>page title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="popup.js" > </script> <!-- <---- Problem, doesn't work in FF but ok in IE/Chrome -->
<body>
```

The script doesn't execute on Firefox like it does on IE and chrome. Why is this?

Could anyone tell me what needs to be done to make it work in FF?

Comment: What error do you get? install firebug on firefox to help you debug http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: I have firebug and it loads the script I guess. It doesn't report any errors.. Just nothing seems to be happening

Comment: @Charles Hover your cursor over any of the buttons in Chrome/IE and a description pops up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `popup.js` file is full of references to a method called `document.getelementbyid`. There is no such method in JavaScript because its a case-sensitive language and thats the reason your code breaks right at the beginning of the `hidep1()` function.:

```
if (document.getelementbyid) {
```

Replace all occurrences of `getelementbyid` with `getElementById` and try again.

Comment: Wow, that did it! Thanks! Hmm, I wonder why the other browsers were able to render it though..

Comment: Well actually your code isn't supposed to work at all because as I already said JavaScript is a case-sensitive language and all browsers that I know of honor that requirement.